# How to make text appear next to (services) heading

Tags: html, css

I know its very easy but I can't figure out. How I can make text appear next to the services heading? Not below the heading.

Here is the code:

```css
.services {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -35px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #f4e409;
}

.services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.services h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.services ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.services ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Services</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>imperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiam mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean on the right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "Services" on the left and the text on the right, please use `width`:

```css
.services {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  background-color: #f4e409;
}

.services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.services h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.services ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45%;
}

.services ul li p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Services</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>imperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiam mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "directly after the h2 without line-break, spacing, etc.":

```css
.services {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  background-color: #f4e409;
}

.services h2 {
  display: inline !important;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.services h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.services ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45%;
}

.services ul li p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Services</h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>imperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiam mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. mperdiet. Etiam n imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. Etiamn imperdiet. </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```